Munkres Topology Section 53 Exercise 6
$\Large\textbf{Motivation}$
At the time of writing this, I am studying algebraic topology wanted to get more familiar with covering spaces. In doing so, I went through some exercises in Munkres' classic, Topology.
I found exercise 6 in section 53 of this book particularly challenging and the resources for verifying potential solutions scattered across the internet, make extraneous assumptions about the spaces, or otherwise non-existent. The intent of this post is to compile a self-contained solution set to this exercise in one spot on MSE for learners to get some hints or verify their own punitive solutions. In doing so, I will present and use the relevant definitions and notation from the book.
These questions, while I found some to be difficult, are not very illuminating; they simply helped me get used to the material. Hopefully this helps another become more familiar and confident with covering spaces :)
Any feedback on mistakes or simplifications and insights are appreciated.

$\S$ 53 Exercise 6

Let $p:E\to B$ be a covering map.
(a) If $B$ is Hausdorff, regular, completely regular, or locally compact Hausdorff, then so is $E$. 
[Hint: If $\{V_{\alpha}\}$ is a partition of $p^{-1}(U)$ into slices, and $C$ is a closed subset of $B$ such that $C\subset U$, then $p^{-1}(C)\cap V_{\alpha}$ is a closed set of $E$.]
(b) If $B$ is compact and $p^{-1}(b)$ is finite for each $b\in B$, then $E$ is compact.


$\Large\textbf{Relevant Definitions}$
Definition (Evenly Covered)

Let $p:E\to B$ be a continuous surjective map. An open subset $U$ of $B$ is said to be evenly covered by $p$ if the inverse image $p^{-1}(U)$ can be written as a union of disjoint open sets $V_{\alpha}$ in $E$ such that for each $\alpha$, the restriction of $p$ to $V_{\alpha}$ is a homeomorphism of $V_{\alpha}$ onto $U$. The collection $\{V_{\alpha}\}$ will be called a partition of $p^{-1}(U)$ into slices. (It will sometimes be useful to give a name to the indexing set for the indices $\alpha$, usually $I$ or $J$.)

Definition (Covering Map/Space)

Let $p:E\to B$ be continuous and surjective. If every point $b$ of $B$ has a neighborhood $U$ that is evenly covered by $p$, then $p$ is called a covering map, and $E$ is said to be a covering space of $B$.

Definition (Neighborhood)

A neighborhood of a point $x$ in a space $X$ is an open set containing $x$.

Definition (Hausdorff)

A space $X$ is called a Hausdorff space if for each pair $x_1,x_2$ of distinct points of $X$, there exist neighborhoods $U_1$ and $U_2$ of $x_1$ and $x_2$, respectively, that are disjoint.

Definition (Regular)

Suppose that one-point sets are closed in a space $X$. Then $X$ is said to be regular if for each pair consisting of a point $x$ and a closed set $B$ disjoint from $x$, there exist disjoint open sets containing $x$ and $B$, respectively.

By Lemma 31.1, in space $X$ where one-point sets are closed, $X$ is regular if and only if given any point $x$ of $X$ and a neighborhood $U$ of $x$, there is a neighborhood $V$ of $x$ such that $\overline{V}\subset U$.
Definition (Completely Regular)

A space $X$ is completely regular if one-point sets are closed in $X$ and if for each point $x_0$ and each closed set $F$ not containing $x_0$, there is a continuous function $f:X\to[0,1]$ such that $f(x_0)=1$ and $f(F)=\{0\}$.

Definition (Locally Compact)

A space $X$ is said to be locally compact at $x$ if there is some compact subspace $C$ of $X$ that contains a neighborhood of $x$. If $X$ is locally compact at each of its points, $X$ is said simply to be locally compact.


Solutions to (a)

B Hausdorff:
(Poof) Omitted. $\square$

B regular:
(Proof) Let $U$ be a neighborhood of $e_0$ in $E$ and set $b_0=p(e_0)$.
Since $p$ is a covering map, there is a neighborhood $U_0$ of $b_0$ in $B$ which is evenly covered by $p$; let $\{V_{\alpha}\}$ be a partition of $p^{-1}(U_0)$ into slices, and say $e_0$ lies in the slice $V_{\alpha_0}$.
There is some neighborhood $V_0$ of $b_0$ whose closure $\overline{V_0}$ is contained in the open set $p(U\cap V_{\alpha_0})$ by regularity of $B$. One would like to produce a neighborhood $V$ of $e_0$ whose closure (in $E$) is contained in $U$, and one place to get started is to consider neighborhoods contained in $V_{\alpha_0}$, as it is sufficient to work locally in the slice containing $e_0$. The set $p^{-1}(V_0) \cap V_{\alpha_0}$ is a good candidate, as it is a relevantly chosen neighborhood of $e_0$, but one needs to ensure that its closure is contained in $U$. To remedy this, define $V$ as $p^{-1}(V_0)\cap U\cap V_{\alpha_0}$, a neighborhood of $e_0$ contained in $U$.
One may note that since the closure in $E$ and the pre-image under $p$ commute (see Lemma below), $\overline{p^{-1}( V_0 )} = p^{-1}( \overline{V_0} )$ is closed in $E$, and in the subspace topology on $U\cap V_{\alpha_0}$, one has
$$\texttt{cl}_{U\cap V_{\alpha_0}}(V) = \overline{V}\cap U\cap V_{\alpha} = \overline{p^{-1}(V_0)}\cap U\cap V_{\alpha_0} = p^{-1}(\overline{V_0})\cap U\cap V_{\alpha_0}$$
hence $p^{-1}(\overline{V_0})\cap U\cap V_{\alpha_0}$ is closed in $U\cap V_{\alpha_0}$.
Ideally, one would like that $p^{-1}( \overline{V_0} )\cap U\cap V_{\alpha_0}$ is closed in $E$ and not just in $U \cap V_{\alpha_0}$, and indeed it is:
$$\begin{align*}
p^{-1}( \overline{V_0} ) \cap U \cap V_{\alpha_0}
&= p^{-1}( \overline{V_0} ) - \bigsqcup_{\alpha \neq \alpha_0}(p^{-1}( \overline{V_0} ) \cap U \cap V_{\alpha})\\
&= p^{-1}( \overline{V_0} ) - \left( p^{-1}( \overline{V_0} ) \cap \bigsqcup_{\alpha\neq\alpha_0}( U \cap V_{\alpha} ) \right)\\
&= p^{-1}( \overline{V_0} ) - \bigsqcup_{\alpha \neq \alpha_0}( U \cap V_{\alpha} )
\end{align*}$$
Now,
$$\overline{V} 
= \overline{p^{-1}(V_0)} \cap \overline{U} \cap \overline{V_{\alpha_0}} 
= p^{-1}(\overline{V_0}) \cap \overline{U} \cap \overline{V_{\alpha_0}}
\supset p^{-1}(\overline{V_0}) \cap U \cap V_{\alpha_0}
\supset V$$
and so $\overline{V} = p^{-1}(\overline{V_0}) \cap U \cap V_{\alpha_0}$ because $\overline{V}$ is the smallest closed subset in $E$ containing $V$. As $\overline{V} \subset U$, it follows that $E$ is regular. $\square$

B completely regular:
(Proof)
If there are no pairs of points and disjoint closed sets in $E$, then by vacuity, $E$ is completely regular. Otherwise, let $e_0 \in E$ and $F$ be a non-empty closed subset of $E$ not containing $e_0$. Set $b_0 = p(e_0)$ and $U = E - F$. There is a neighborhood $U_0$ of $b_0$ evenly covered by $p$ and some partition $\{V_{\alpha}\}$ of $p^{-1}(U_0)$ into slices with $e_0$ in the slice $V_{\alpha_0}$.
Set $V_0=p(U \cap V_{\alpha_0})$. $V_0$ is a subset of $U_0$ and is evenly covered by $p$ via the partition of slices $V_{\alpha}' = V_{\alpha} \cap p^{-1}(V_0)$, as $p$ is a homeomorphism of $V_{\alpha}$ and $U_0$ for each $\alpha$. Note that $V_{\alpha_0}' = V_{\alpha_0} \cap U$.
Since $B$ is completely regular, then it is regular, so there is a neighborhood $W$ of $b_0$ whose closure is contained in $V_0$. By the complete regularity assumption on $B$, there is a continuous, real-valued function $f:B \to [0,1]$ such that $f(b_0) = 1$ and $f(B - W) = \{0\}$.
Simply post-composing $p$ with $f$ will result in a real valued function with $f\circ p : E \to [0,1]$ with $f(e_0) = 1$, but it was not chosen with any regards for our closed set $F$. Instead, define $\widetilde{f} : E \to [0,1]$ as
$$\widetilde{f}(x) = 
\begin{cases}
f\circ p(x) &\text{ if } x \in V_{\alpha_0}'\\
0 &\text{ if } x \in \left(\bigsqcup_{\alpha \neq \alpha_0}V_{\alpha'}\right)\cup (E - p^{-1}(\overline{W}))
\end{cases}
$$
This function is well-defined since
$$V_{\alpha_0}' 
\cup \left[\left(\bigsqcup_{\alpha \neq \alpha_0}V_{\alpha'}\right)\cup (E - p^{-1}(\overline{W}))\right] 
= p^{-1}(V_0)\cup (E - p^{-1}(\overline{W})) 
= E$$
and for
$$x\in V_{\alpha_0}'
\cap \left[\left(\bigsqcup_{\alpha \neq \alpha_0}V_{\alpha'}\right)\cup (E - p^{-1}(\overline{W}))\right] 
= V_{\alpha_0}' - p^{-1}(\overline{W}),$$
$p(x)\in B - \overline{W}\subset B - W$ so $p(x) = 0$, and so $\widetilde{f}$ agrees on the intersection of $V_{\alpha_0}'$ and $\left(\bigsqcup_{\alpha \neq \alpha_0}V_{\alpha'}\right)\cup (E - p^{-1}(\overline{W}))$. By the pasting lemma, $\widetilde{f}$ is continuous on $E$.
Making the final check, as $V_{\alpha_0}'\subset U$, write $F = E - U\subset E - V_{\alpha_0}'$ and observe that $\widetilde{f}(F) = \{0\}$. $\square$

B Locally Compact Hausdorff
$E$ is Hausdorff by the first variant of this problem since $B$ is. It suffices to show that $E$ is locally compact. Fix $e_0 \in E$ and set $b_0 = p(e_0)$. There is an neighborhood $U_0$ of $b_0$ evenly covered by $p$ and some partition $\{V_{\alpha}\}$ of $p^{-1}(U_0)$ into slices with $e_0$ in the slice $V_{\alpha_0}$.
Since $B$ is locally compact at $b_0$, there is a compact set $C_0$ containing a neighborhood $U$ of $b_0$. In addition, as $U\cap U_0\subset U\subset C_0$ and closed subspaces of compact spaces are closed, then $$\overline{U\cap U_0} = \overline{U}\cap \overline{U_0}\subset \overline{U}\subset C_0$$ is compact.
By similar reasoning as in the case when $B$ was regular,
$$\overline{p^{-1}(U\cap U_0)\cap V_{\alpha_0}} = p^{-1}(\overline{U\cap U_0})\cap V_{\alpha_0}\supset p^{-1}(U\cap V_0)\cap V_{\alpha_0}.$$
Since $p\circ \iota_{V_{\alpha_0}}: V_{\alpha_0}\to U_0$ is a homeomorphism, then
$(p\circ\iota_{V_{\alpha_0}})^{-1}(\overline{U\cap U_0}) = p^{-1}(\overline{U\cap U_0})\cap V_{\alpha_0}$ is compact. It follows that $e_0$ is contained in a compact set containing a neighborhood of $e_0$, thus $E$ is locally compact at $e_0$. Since $e_0\in E$ was arbitrary, then $E$ is locally compact. $\square$
Solution to (b)

(Proof) It suffices to show that $p$ is a perfect map by showing that it is closed, since perfect maps are also proper, and so $E = p^{-1}(B)$ is compact.
Let $F$ be a closed subset of $E$ and let $b_0 \in B - p(F)$. There is an evenly covered neighborhood $U_0$ of $b_0$ with partition $\{V_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in I}$ of $p^{-1}(U_0)$ into slices.
Since $p^{-1}(b_0)$ is finite and meets each $V_{\alpha}$ exactly once, it follows that $I$ is finite.
Set $V_{\alpha}' = V_{\alpha}\cap (E - F)$ for each $\alpha \in I$ and set $U_{b_0} = \displaystyle\bigcap_{\alpha \in I}p(V_{\alpha}')$. It is clear that each $V_{\alpha}'$ is an open neighborhood of the unique point in $p^{-1}(b_0)\cap V_{\alpha}$ and that $U_{b_0}$ is a neighborhood of $b_0$.
For $b \in U_{b_0}$, if $b = p(x)$ for some $x \in C$, then $x \in p^{-1}(b)$. Now $x = e_{\alpha}$ some $e_{\alpha} \in V_{\alpha}' = V_{\alpha} \cap (E - F)$, but $e_{\alpha}$ is not in $F$, a contradiction. This demonstrates that $U_{b_0}$ is a neighborhood of $b_0$ disjoint from $p(F)$, hence $p$ is closed. $\square$

Lemma

If $f:X\to Y$ is continuous and open or  continuous and closed, then for any subset $V$ of $Y$,
$$\overline{f^{-1}(V)}=f^{-1}(\overline{V})$$
$$\text{ and }$$
$$f^{-1}(V)^{\circ} = f^{-1}(V^{\circ})$$

